# Elm decode json object with array

Tags: json, elm

Im totally new in ELM. Im trying to get data from get response.

Now im trying to make decoder for that. I have json like this:

```
{
  data: [
        {
            "price" = 300.5
        },
        {
            "price" = 1005
        }
    ]
}
```

All i need is get lowest price and return it. (At least return each price).

Now i stacked on Decode.index.

```
priceDecoder : Decode.Decoder String
priceDecoder = 
    Decode.field "data" Decode.list
```

What should i do next?

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with the question itself. First, you're not posting the error you get. The error I get is this:

```
The 2nd argument to `field` is not what I expect:

25|     Decode.field "data" Decode.list
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
This `list` value is a:

    Decode.Decoder a -> Decode.Decoder (List a)

But `field` needs the 2nd argument to be:

    Decode.Decoder a
```

Second, the JSON you've posted is not valid, `data` should be enclosed in quotes and properties and values should be separated by `:`, not `=`.

Thirdly, the type of `priceDecoder` seems wrong since the JSON contains no `String` data, or you're not specifying that you also want to convert the `Float` to a `String`. I will assume the type is just wrong.

So, the error you (or at least I) get says that `list` is a function `Decoder a -> Decoder (List a)`, while it expects just a `Decoder a` value. This is because `list` expects a `Decoder a` to be passed to it, which it will use to decode each item in the list.

The decoder we'll use is `Decode.field "price" Decode.float`, which will decode the "price" field of the object as a `Float`.

I'll also change the type of `priceDecoder` from `Decoder String` to `Decoder (List Float)`, since the price is a `Float` and we're decoding a `List` of them, not just getting the first or last value or something like that. I assume that's what you want since you say "at least return each price'.

The `priceDecoder` we get then is:

```
priceDecoder : Decode.Decoder (List Float)
priceDecoder = 
    Decode.field "data" (Decode.list (Decode.field "price" Decode.float))
```